# Is an intersection of infinitely many normal subgroups of the same index a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Say $G$ has infinitely normal subgroups of index $n$ call them $H_i$ for $i = 0,1,2..$

Is $\bigcap H_i$ normal in $G$?

Does anyone know a proof or counter example?

Thanks

Comment: The intersection of any number of normal subgroups is always normal and the proof is as direct as it can be.

Comment: [Here's a proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Normal_Subgroups_is_Normal). Search engines are your friends.

Comment: Almost always a construction which creates a subgroup out of all the subgroups having a particular property is a characteristic subgroup and hence normal. So the intersection of all the subgroups of index $m$ would be normal for this reason, without the subgroups having to be normal. [Conjugation acts on the set of subgroups of index $m$]

Comment: Cool... So intersection of infinite family of normal subgroups of $G$ is characteristic in $G$?

Comment: @FireFenix777: No. And nobody said that.